# haxelib run can't start new threads?

Tags: haxe, neko, haxelib

I'm getting an exception when trying to use the [`haxelib run` command](https://lib.haxe.org/documentation/using-haxelib/#run) on my test Haxelib:

```
haxelib run haxelib-test
```

> D:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std/neko/vm/Thread.hx:54: characters 20-71 : Can't create thread from within a macro

Without threading everything works okay.

Haxe code:

```
import neko.vm.Thread;

class Main {
    static function main() {
        trace("starting");
        var commandsThread = Thread.create(read);
        trace("ending");
    }

    static function read() {
        trace("new thread");
    }
}
```

My `haxelib.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "haxelib-test",
    "license": "MIT",
    "tags": [],
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "classPath": "src/",
    "main": "Main"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Haxelib docs](https://lib.haxe.org/documentation/using-haxelib/#run) you linked:

> Libraries with either a `run.n` helper or a main class defined in `haxelib.json`, can be executed using `haxelib run`.

Since you're providing a `main` class, Haxelib is trying to run your code in Haxe's built-in macro interpreter using the `--interp` argument.

Haxe 3's macro interpreter did not support threading, hence the error. You can work around this by compiling a `run.n` file and packaging that with your library, so the script is executed in Neko VM:

```
haxe -main Main -neko run.n
```

Haxe 4 [introduced](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/6797) threading support for its new macro interpreter called ["Eval"](https://haxe.org/blog/eval/) in the `preview.5` release. Starting with that version, you can use [`eval.vm.Thread`](https://api.haxe.org/v/development/eval/vm/Thread.html). However, note that this would make your Haxelib's `run` command not work for people running older Haxe versions. So if you're going for maximum compatibility, stick to Neko for now.